# jQuery.print.js save generated PDF to server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pdf

I'm trying to get the jQuery.print.js plugin working to save the generated .PDF as a file on server. My guess is that I have to do it with an AJAX call but I don't know how to pick the raw data of the generated PDF in a variable and pass it to a PHP function that does the saving. I'm using jQuery.print.js version 1.5.1.

My code is:

```
`$('#saveOffer').click(function() {
    $("#offerList").print({
        globalStyles : false,
        mediaPrint : false,
        stylesheet : "../dist/css/style.css",
        iframe : false,
        noPrintSelector : ".btn",
        title: pageTitle
    });
});`
```

The above code is opening a print dialog in the browser, but I want to save the PDF in a variable and save it on the disk. Any clues on how to get this thing done?